# How to exclude META-INF WARNING after running mvn clean install?

Tags: maven, meta-inf

the warnings look like this. Then under are my plugins How should I configure plugins to remove all META-INF warnings? the warnings look like this. Then under are my plugins How should I configure plugins to remove all META-INF warnings? Hier is one explanation that I have found. [Maven Shade plugin: how resolve the warning message "define 1 overlapping resource: [WARNING] - META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64110058/maven-shade-plugin-how-resolve-the-warning-message-define-1-overlapping-resour)

```
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar, HikariCP-java7-2.4.13.jar, MigLayout-3.7.2.jar, SparseBitSet-1.2.jar, TeoClientTest.jar, activemq-client-5.17.0.jar, animal-sniffer-annotations-1.17.jar, ant-1.10.12.jar, ant-antlr-1.10.12.jar, ant-junit-1.10.12.jar, ant-launcher-1.10.12.jar, asm-7.1.jar, bapi-skif-11.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar, byte-buddy-1.8.12.jar, c3p0-0.9.5.4.jar, cglib-3.3.0.jar, checker-qual-2.5.2.jar, classmate-1.4.0.jar, cloning-1.9.12.jar, commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar, commons-cli-1.4.jar, commons-codec-1.15.jar, commons-collections-3.2.2.jar, commons-collections4-4.4.jar, commons-compiler-3.1.6.jar, commons-compress-1.19.jar, commons-digester-2.1.jar, commons-email-1.5.jar, commons-io-2.11.0.jar, commons-lang-2.6.jar, commons-lang3-3.4.jar, commons-math3-3.6.1.jar, curvesapi-1.06.jar, ecj-3.21.0.jar, error_prone_annotations-2.2.0.jar, failureaccess-1.0.1.jar, geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar, groovy-3.0.10.jar, groovy-ant-3.0.10.jar, groovy-astbuilder-3.0.10.jar, groovy-cli-picocli-3.0.10.jar, groovy-console-3.0.10.jar, groovy-datetime-3.0.10.jar, groovy-docgenerator-3.0.10.jar, groovy-groovydoc-3.0.10.jar, groovy-groovysh-3.0.10.jar, groovy-jmx-3.0.10.jar, groovy-json-3.0.10.jar, groovy-jsr223-3.0.10.jar, groovy-macro-3.0.10.jar, groovy-nio-3.0.10.jar, groovy-servlet-3.0.10.jar, groovy-sql-3.0.10.jar, groovy-swing-3.0.10.jar, groovy-templates-3.0.10.jar, groovy-test-3.0.10.jar, groovy-test-junit5-3.0.10.jar, groovy-testng-3.0.10.jar, groovy-xml-3.0.10.jar, gson-2.9.0.jar, guava-27.0.1-jre.jar, hawtbuf-1.11.jar, httpclient-4.5.13.jar, httpcore-4.4.13.jar, httpmime-4.5.13.jar, itext-2.1.7.js9.jar, itextpdf-5.5.6.jar, j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar, jackson-annotations-2.11.3.jar, jackson-core-2.11.3.jar, jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar, jackson-dataformat-xml-2.11.3.jar, jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.11.3.jar, jakarta.activation-2.0.1.jar, janino-3.1.6.jar, jasperreports-6.19.0.jar, javaparser-core-3.24.0.jar, javassist-3.28.0-GA.jar, javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar, javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar, javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar, javax.mail-1.5.6.jar, jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar, jaxb-core-3.0.2.jar, jaxb-impl-3.0.2.jar, jaxb-runtime-2.4.0-b180830.0438.jar, jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.35.jar, jcommander-1.78.jar, jcommon-1.0.24.jar, jdom2-2.0.6.1.jar, jfreechart-1.5.3.jar, jide-action-3.7.10.jar, jide-charts-3.7.10.jar, jide-common-3.7.10.jar, jide-components-3.7.10.jar, jide-dashboard-3.7.10.jar, jide-dock-3.7.10.jar, jide-editor-3.7.10.jar, jide-gantt-3.7.10.jar, jide-grids-3.7.10.jar, jide-pivot-3.7.10.jar, jide-plaf-3.7.10.jar, jide-shortcut-3.7.10.jar, jline-2.14.6.jar, jna-5.11.0.jar, jna-platform-5.11.0.jar, joda-time-2.10.14.jar, jollyday-0.5.10.jar, jquery-3.5.1.jar, jsr305-3.0.2.jar, jul-to-slf4j-1.7.35.jar, junit-jupiter-api-5.8.2.jar, junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar, junit-platform-commons-1.8.2.jar, junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar, junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar, listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar, log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.35.jar, logback-classic-1.2.10.jar, logback-core-1.2.10.jar, mapstruct-1.2.0.Final.jar, mchange-commons-java-0.2.15.jar, mybatis-3.5.7.jar, objenesis-3.0.1.jar, ojdbc11-21.5.0.0.jar, opencsv-2.3.jar, opentest4j-1.2.0.jar, picocli-4.6.1.jar, plac-exif-21.2.0.0.jar, poi-4.1.2.jar, poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar, qdox-1.12.1.jar, quartz-2.3.2.jar, reflections-0.10.2.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.35.jar, spring-aop-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, spring-beans-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, spring-context-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, spring-context-support-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, spring-core-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, spring-expression-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, spring-jdbc-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, spring-jms-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, spring-messaging-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, spring-orm-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, spring-oxm-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar, spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar, spring-security-core-5.4.10.jar, spring-tx-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, spring-web-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, spring-webmvc-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar, springfox-core-2.9.2.jar, springfox-schema-2.9.2.jar, springfox-spi-2.9.2.jar, springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar, springfox-swagger-common-2.9.2.jar, springfox-swagger-ui-2.9.2.jar, springfox-swagger2-2.9.2.jar, stax-ex-1.8.jar, stax2-api-4.2.1.jar, swagger-annotations-1.5.20.jar, swagger-models-1.5.20.jar, teo-common-report-10.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, teo-common-ui-10.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, teo-common-ui-report-10.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, teo-common-util-10.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, teo-skif-12.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, testng-7.5.jar, threeten-extra-1.5.0.jar, ucp-21.5.0.0.jar, woodstox-core-6.2.1.jar, xbean-spring-4.20.jar, xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar define 1 overlapping resource:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[WARNING] activemq-client-5.17.0.jar, cglib-3.3.0.jar, classmate-1.4.0.jar, geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar, groovy-3.0.10.jar, groovy-ant-3.0.10.jar, groovy-astbuilder-3.0.10.jar, groovy-cli-picocli-3.0.10.jar, groovy-console-3.0.10.jar, groovy-datetime-3.0.10.jar, groovy-docgenerator-3.0.10.jar, groovy-groovydoc-3.0.10.jar, groovy-groovysh-3.0.10.jar, groovy-jmx-3.0.10.jar, groovy-json-3.0.10.jar, groovy-jsr223-3.0.10.jar, groovy-macro-3.0.10.jar, groovy-nio-3.0.10.jar, groovy-servlet-3.0.10.jar, groovy-sql-3.0.10.jar, groovy-swing-3.0.10.jar, groovy-templates-3.0.10.jar, groovy-test-3.0.10.jar, groovy-test-junit5-3.0.10.jar, groovy-testng-3.0.10.jar, groovy-xml-3.0.10.jar, httpclient-4.5.13.jar, httpcore-4.4.13.jar, httpmime-4.5.13.jar, jackson-annotations-2.11.3.jar, jackson-core-2.11.3.jar, jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar, jackson-dataformat-xml-2.11.3.jar, jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.11.3.jar, jna-5.11.0.jar, jna-platform-5.11.0.jar, mybatis-3.5.7.jar, objenesis-3.0.1.jar, poi-4.1.2.jar, poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar, stax2-api-4.2.1.jar, woodstox-core-6.2.1.jar, xbean-spring-4.20.jar define 1 overlapping resource:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/LICENSE
[WARNING] activemq-client-5.17.0.jar, cglib-3.3.0.jar, classmate-1.4.0.jar, geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar, groovy-3.0.10.jar, groovy-ant-3.0.10.jar, groovy-astbuilder-3.0.10.jar, groovy-cli-picocli-3.0.10.jar, groovy-console-3.0.10.jar, groovy-datetime-3.0.10.jar, groovy-docgenerator-3.0.10.jar, groovy-groovydoc-3.0.10.jar, groovy-groovysh-3.0.10.jar, groovy-jmx-3.0.10.jar, groovy-json-3.0.10.jar, groovy-jsr223-3.0.10.jar, groovy-macro-3.0.10.jar, groovy-nio-3.0.10.jar, groovy-servlet-3.0.10.jar, groovy-sql-3.0.10.jar, groovy-swing-3.0.10.jar, groovy-templates-3.0.10.jar, groovy-test-3.0.10.jar, groovy-test-junit5-3.0.10.jar, groovy-testng-3.0.10.jar, groovy-xml-3.0.10.jar, httpclient-4.5.13.jar, httpcore-4.4.13.jar, httpmime-4.5.13.jar, jackson-core-2.11.3.jar, jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar, jackson-dataformat-xml-2.11.3.jar, jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.11.3.jar, mybatis-3.5.7.jar, objenesis-3.0.1.jar, poi-4.1.2.jar, poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar, xbean-spring-4.20.jar define 1 //
[WARNING] maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are
[WARNING] present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only one
[WARNING] single version of the class is copied to the uber jar.
[WARNING] Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these warnings,
[WARNING] otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on
[WARNING] mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output.
[WARNING] See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
```

How can I remove these WARNINGS?

My plugins looks like this:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        <inLibsFilter>!META-INF/**,!META-INF/versions/9/**.class</inLibsFilter>
                    </configuration>
                      <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.basepom.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>duplicate-finder-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <printEqualFiles>false</printEqualFiles>
                    <failBuildInCaseOfDifferentContentConflict>false</failBuildInCaseOfDifferentContentConflict>
                    <failBuildInCaseOfEqualContentConflict>false</failBuildInCaseOfEqualContentConflict>
                    <failBuildInCaseOfConflict>false</failBuildInCaseOfConflict>
                    <checkCompileClasspath>true</checkCompileClasspath>
                    <checkRuntimeClasspath>true</checkRuntimeClasspath>
                    <checkTestClasspath>false</checkTestClasspath>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <quiet>false</quiet>
                    <preferLocal>true</preferLocal>
                    <useResultFile>true</useResultFile>
                    <resultFileMinClasspathCount>2</resultFileMinClasspathCount>
                    <resultFile>${project.build.directory}/duplicate-finder-result.xml</resultFile>
                    <includeBootClasspath>false</includeBootClasspath>
                    <bootClasspathProperty>sun.boot.class.path</bootClasspathProperty>
                    <useDefaultResourceIgnoreList>true</useDefaultResourceIgnoreList>
                    <includePomProjects>false</includePomProjects>
                    <useDefaultResourceIgnoreList>true</useDefaultResourceIgnoreList>
                    <ignoredResourcePatterns>
                        

<ignoredResourcePattern>jasperreports_extension\.properties</ignoredResourcePattern>
                        <ignoredResourcePattern>\.project</ignoredResourcePattern>
                        <ignoredResourcePattern>.*\.png$</ignoredResourcePattern>
                        <ignoredResourcePattern>.*\.txt$</ignoredResourcePattern>
                        <ignoredResourcePattern>.*\.json$</ignoredResourcePattern>
                        <ignoredResourcePattern>.*\.xml$</ignoredResourcePattern>
                        <ignoredResourcePattern>.*\.properties$</ignoredResourcePattern>
                        <ignoredResourcePattern>.*\.md$</ignoredResourcePattern>
                    </ignoredResourcePatterns>
                    <ignoredClassPatterns>
                        <ignoredClassPattern>(META-INF)</ignoredClassPattern>
                    </ignoredClassPatterns>
                    <!-- Beispiele <ignoredResourcePatterns> jasperreports_extension.properties 
                        <ignoredResourcePattern>.*index\.html$</ignoredResourcePattern> </ignoredResourcePatterns> 
                        <ignoredClassPatterns> <ignoredClassPattern>javax.*$</ignoredClassPattern> 
                        </ignoredClassPatterns> -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <filters>
                            <filter>
                              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                              <!-- We need to exclude the signatures for any signed jars otherwise
                                   we get an exception. -->
                              <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.*</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                              </excludes>
                            </filter>
                          </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: The warning says that there are duplicate jars in your dependency tree. Try running `mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true` and exclude the duplicates as the warning suggests

Answer (score 3):

This example works for me:

```
...
<configuration>
    <transformers>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <mainClass>com.example.pikachu.Pikachu</mainClass>
        </transformer>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.DontIncludeResourceTransformer">
            <resource>MANIFEST.MF</resource>
        </transformer>
    </transformers>
    <filters>
        <filter>
            <artifact>com.example.pikachu:*</artifact>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.MF</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </filter>
    </filters>
</configuration>
...
```

Comment: Nice; the `DontIncludeResourceTransformer` part with `<resource>MANIFEST.MF</resource>` solved the problem with overlapping `MANIFEST.MF` files for me. Is there some reason you still need the `<exclude>META-INF/*.MF</exclude>` filter? Are there some other files in particular you were wanting to exclude in addition to `MANIFEST.MF`?